# In the context of the holographic principle, is the bulk-boundary correspondence due to entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, quantum-entanglement, ads-cft, holographic-principle

According to the holographic principle, a "bulk" region of D dimensions corresponds to a "boundary" region of D-1 dimensions. In this context, the laws of physics of the bulk can be "encoded" on the boundary, so there is a correspondence between the bulk and the boundary.

My question is:

Does this correspondence arise because there is an entanglement between the bulk region and the boundary? Could they become unentangled, so that the fundamental laws of physics in the boundary could become radically different compared to those in the bulk?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to formulate precisely the idea of entanglement between bulk and boundary regions. In fact, usually when we study entanglement in QFT, we consider some Cauchy slice $\Sigma$ and a split of $\Sigma$ into complementary regions $A$ and $B$, so that $\Sigma = A\cup B$ and we discuss entanglement between degrees of freedom in $A$ and $B$. In particular, both $A$ and $B$ have the same dimension. In what you discuss you consider the whole space $M$ and its boundary $\partial M$, which in particular have different dimensions. So it seems a little different from the usual story.

Comment: Nevertheless, entanglement is likely to play an important role in the holographic principle. More precisely, there seems to be some connection between quantum entanglement on the boundary and the emergence of a semi-classical geometry in the bulk. See for a very recent discussion in the context of dS/CFT and references 1-4 of that paper for the known version of this proposal in the context of AdS/CFT.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of holography is that the bulk degrees of freedom and the boundary degrees of freedom are the same. They can't be entangled with themselves.

In a simple holographic universe consisting of a single qubit, there is a description of an arbitrary state $α|0\rangle + β|1\rangle$ as a configuration of the bulk, and another description of it as a configuration of the boundary, and you can choose to use either description. There are no states like $(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)/\sqrt2$ because there are no states $|00\rangle$ or $|11\rangle$, only $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$.

Even if the bulk and boundary states were distinct, entanglement couldn't explain their evolving in lockstep, because entangled subsystems don't evolve in lockstep; they just have correlated initial states. You could argue that identical subsystems evolving under identical laws with no nonunitary collapse would remain identical forever, but that would apply just as well to unentangled initial conditions ($|ψ\rangle\otimes|ψ\rangle$).